# Add event delegation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to jQuery and I have a question about event delegation.
Here below is a series of codes from javascript book

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
      <button class="accordion-control">Classics</button>
      <div class="accordion-panel">
        <p>If you ...</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="accordion-control">The Flower Series</button>
      <div class="accordion-panel">
        <p>Take your ...</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="accordion-control">Salt o' The Sea</button>
      <div class="accordion-panel">
        <p>Ahoy! ....</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();                  
     $(this).next('.accordion-panel')            
         .not(':animated')                   
         .slideToggle();                      
});
```

I was wondering since we have already selected '.accordion',then why should we also need to select  '.accordion-control'? And I used to believe the formula should be `$(selector).on(event,function)`,so there is another selector after the event?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `accordion` refer to the ancestor. The binding will be on the `click` event, for one of it's descendant called `accordion-control`.
The ancestor is used when the descendant is not exist yet (for example if your `accordion-control` are created using script and not exist from page loading (in HTML) - and then you cannot bind event to non-existing elements. If it's not your case (means your `accordion-conrtol`'s are exist from the beginning), you can also use the `$(selector).click(function)` for that:
`$('accordion-control').click(function (event) { //your code });`

For more information you can look at: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Gotcha! But If I use javascript instead of jQuery, should I need to have "accordion-control" ?

Comment: Edit the answer for you, please look again (and please accept my answer if it helped you) :-)